# Memory allocation in python

Tags: python, memory

I create a list with three elements named l after that I copy all the content of the list into the list y. But when I print the address of them in the memory I don't understand why this is not the same address. Why y is not a reference of l, and if I want that y will be a reference of l so that they will have the same address. How can I do this ?

This is my code

```
l = [8,12,3]
y = l[:]

print l
print y

print id(l)
print id(y)
```

Display on the screeen :

```
[8, 12, 3]
[8, 12, 3]
40894592 
40837072
```

Comment: If you wanted two references to the same list, why did you *explicitly* create a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[:]` copies the content of `l` to a new list `y`, so they need to be in different addresses. To make `y` a reference of `l`, simply write

```
y = l
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a slice of a list creates a new list. id returns the address of each list.

Answer (score 0):

A good point is that if you write this statement

```
l = [8,12,3],
```

Python creates a pointer from the object `l` to a list `[8, 12, 3]`.

In case you make this statement

```
y = l,
```

Then the object `y` points to `l` and if you change `l`, `y` will be also changed.

In case you write

```
y = list(l),
```

the object `y` points to a new list. Then if you modify `l`, values in `y` remain unchanged.